# How to convert a SQL query to a multidimensional hash?

Tags: dictionary, multidimensional-array, hash

I am wishing to have a multidimensional hash, given a query which joins 4 relevant tables.

Mainly I want this to serve a screen where I have three levels of information. When I click Process, I get a table with activities, and when clicking activities, get a table with both pollution_origins and sub_pollution_origins.

So, I have 5 models, where one of them is a relational one (process_model_maps), which connects the other four.

There is an hierarchy between them (sub_pollution_origin_models are inside pollution_origin_models, which are inside of activity_models, which are part of at least one process_model)

Currently I have this:

**_process_models_maps_list.html.erb**

```
<table id="all_processes">
  <tbody>
    <% @process_models.each do |process_model| %>
      <tr class="process_line_color"> <td><%= process_model.name %></td> </tr>
      <tr> 
        <%= render partial: "process_activities", 
     locals: { process_model: process_model} %>                 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_process_activities.html.erb**

```
<table id = "process_activities"> 
      <tbody>
        <% process_model.activity_models.each do |activity_model| %>
        <tr class="activity_line_color"> <td><%= activity_model.name %></td> </tr>
        <tr> 
        <%= render partial: "activity_sub_pollution_origin_models", 
    locals: { activity_model: activity_model} %>
        </tr> <!-- row activity_model details-->
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**_activity_sub_pollution_origin_models.html.erb**

```
<table id = "activity_details"> 
  <tbody>
    <% activity_model.process_model_maps.each do |process_model_map| %>
    <tr> 
      <td> <%= process_model_map.pollution_origin_model.name  %></td>
      <td> <%= process_model_map.sub_pollution_origin_model.name  %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue is that if I just use regular activerecord, rails goes on and sets a great number of queries, which kills performance for the screen.

So I thought that if I had a pre-loaded hash somehow, this would make the task easier for the end user.

in my **ProcessModel.rb** I have

```
  def self.get_tree_map

    joins(process_model_maps: [:activity_model, :pollution_origin_model, :sub_pollution_origin_model]).select("process_models.id, process_models.name, activity_models.id,activity_models.name, process_model_maps.id , pollution_origin_models.name,sub_pollution_origin_models.name")

  end
```

and am now thinking on getting something like:

{`Project_id: 1, name: Fundicao, {activity_id:1, name: Decapagem,{process_model_maps_id: 2, pollution_origin_models_id: 1, pollution_origin_models_name: " Energia ", sub_pollution_origin_models_id: 1, sub_pollution_origin_models_name: "Energia Eletrica" },...}}}`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
@process_models = Process.all.joins(:activities).merge(
  Activity.joins(:pollution_origins))
```

That should fetch all of the data you want with a single SQL call.